# Send a campaign more than once in MailChimp

Tags: php, mailchimp

I am trying to send an email to users based on their status. The first email needs to be sent after 2 hours, and a second one after 24 hours.

I am running a PHP script that checks for users who belong to a state and I sent the first email to them using the send API call, the problem now, is that when the script runs again (a crobtab that runs every 20 mins), I cannot send the campaign again since apparently you can send a campaign only once.

I am putting the cid directly in my PHP code, so I cannot go and edit the code everytime I want to run the crontab!

Do I have to use the `campaigncreate()`method everytime the crontab runs? 
https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/campaigns/create.php

It would be better if there is an easier way, since an account cannot have more than 32,000 campaigns.

Comment: Are you using shared hosting? Is there a limit on PHP emails you can send?  If it were me I would export the MailChimp campaign template into a HTML file, then send it as a HTML email with PHP mail() rather than with MailChimp, then you can send it again in 24 hours. You can still host all the images and create nice designer emails on MailChimp

Comment: @jojojohn, I m using mailChimp mainly for the tracking abilities it provides. the php mail is not much of use for analytics!

Comment: OK I see. Maybe another mail service that lets you send mails according  to what people do in your website eg http://customer.io/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mailchimp is a bulk email service and isn't designed to send transactional emails.

You should instead try to use [Mandrill](http://mandrill.com/), a transactional email service built by the same company. And their [API](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.php.html) is quite simple to use.

Then, you can indeed run your PHP script every hour (or x minutes) to send emails based on user status.

Comment: Thank you. This was the second option. I went for the option of buying the premium version, and using automation.